# Need simple generic vba macro script to change value of cell based on value of other cell

Tags: vba, excel

Need simple generic vba macro script to change value of cell based on value of other cell.

I have values in the range from e1:e1000. In any of these cell in the range if the value is "x" then its adjacent 2 cells in respective rows should change the value to "y"

eg: if e1 = "x" then f1 = "y" and g1 = "y"

Similarly for other cells too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Srikanth, Reafidy has a point. Even I would prefer a formula. However if you still want a VBA code here it is.

**USING FORMULA**

Type this in Cell F1 and G1 and simply drag it down till F1000 and G1000

=IF(E1="X","Y","")

**USING CODE**

```
Sub Sample()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:F1000").Formula = "=If(E1=""X"",""Y"","""")"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G1:G1000").Formula = "=If(E1=""X"",""Y"","""")"
End Sub
```

**FOLLOW UP**

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:F1000").Formula = "=If(D1=""Ready"",""Ready"","""")"
```

OR if you do not want to use the formulas altogether then use this

```
Sub Sample()
    For i = 1 To 1000
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
            If .Range("D" & i).Value = "Ready" Then _
            .Range("F" & i).Value = "Ready" Else .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

**MORE FOLLOW UP**

> > > thanks for reply. I tried using the one without the formula,But even this is failing. i have put the code inside Worksheet_Change function. its throwing error with 'With Sheets("Sheet1")' line, even though Worksheet_Change is in Sheet1. know why? – Srikanth Yadake 11 mins ago

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D1:D1000")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Value = "Ready" Then _
        Target.Offset(, 2).Value = "Ready" Else Target.Offset(, 2).Value = ""
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: i tried with the above code, its not functioning. Direct formula cant be used because the cell is binded with list values. the code which I used looks like below:Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:F1000").Formula = "=If(Range(""D1:D1000"")=""Ready"",""Ready"","""")"

Comment: when value in D col on any row is changed to Ready the value in the same row of F column should also change to Ready.

Comment: @Srikanth Yadake: I have updated the code above. :) See "FOLLOW UP"

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried using the one without the formula,But even this is failing. i have put  the code inside Worksheet_Change function. its throwing error with 'With Sheets("Sheet1")' line, even though Worksheet_Change is in Sheet1. know why?

Comment: @Srikanth Yadake: You cannot use that code in as it is in worksheet Change event. One moment updating the code

Comment: Thanks a ton.. this is working.. can you let know why wasnt it functioning before?

Comment: Because you were using it Worksheet Change event :) Compare both the codes and see what is the difference :)

Comment: If Target.Value = "Ready" Then _
        Target.Offset(, 2).Value = ""
        Target.Offset(, 1).Value = ""
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Reviewed" Then _
        Target.Offset(, 2).Value = "Reviewed"
        Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "Reviewed"
        ElseIf Target.Value = "To Be Reviewed" Then _
         Target.Offset(, 2).Value = "To Be Reviewed"
        Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "To Be Reviewed"

Comment: chk the above code...I have added some more conditions but only the first "Ready" condition is working fine, others are not. why so?

Comment: That is because you have "_" at the end of every elseif. Remove that. and also add an endif

Comment: If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D1:D1000")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Value = "Ready" Then _
        Target.Offset(, 2).Value = ""
        Target.Offset(, 1).Value = ""
        
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Reviewed" Then
        Target.Offset(, 2).Value = "Reviewed"
        Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "Reviewed"
        
        ElseIf Target.Value = "To Be Reviewed" Then
         Target.Offset(, 2).Value = "To Be Reviewed"
        Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "To Be Reviewed"
        
   End If
    
End If

Comment: Remove "_" after [= "Ready" Then]

Comment: Please post the code above and also please mention what results are you expecting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8148/discussion-between-sriyad-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: i also need another help.. whr in the vice versa should work, as shown below.. help me wen u are free.. i tried out but not working..
ElseIf Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "Reviewed" And Target.Offset(, 2).Value = "Reviewed" Then 
Target.Value = "Reviewed"
when col 'E' and col 'F' values are changed to 'Reviewed' col 'D' should change to 'Reviewed'

Comment: Sriyad, you cannot forever keep on asking further questions in this same old question. I would recommend starting a new question and link it to this question :)